# Drone falling on one side while taking off

Tags: brushless-motors, flysky, arduino-drone

i made a quadcopter using arduino and am quite new to it. when i 1st flew it it fell on one of the sides
i used:
1800kv golden bldc motor
30 amp esc
1045 propellers
arduino uno and mpu 6050
fsi6 transmitter and reciever

what i fell is that problem is in calibrating because when i callibrated the motors and the increase throtle at 1st they all appear to start at same time but when i increase the throttle really really slow then i observe that all motors are not starting at the same time and same speed . what could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't matter that the motors start at slightly different times due to slight calibration errors. The flight controller should detect that it is not level and increase the throttle on the low motor to compensate. It is entirely possible to fly with mismatched motors and props, or a CG that isn't perfectly balanced.

If one motor doesn't take off, it usually means that it's thrusting in the wrong direction. Either the motor is reversed or it has the wrong direction of prop.

If the drone constantly wants to tip in one direction, the flight controller's calibration of 'level' is wrong. In Beta Flight there's a page that shows which way up the flight controller thinks it is, and a 'recalibrate' button, but if you've written your own arduino code you'll have to debug this yourself.

Comment: i am using arduino as the controller and don't have the acces to beta flight and i have double checked the direction of props and motors they are fine then what could be the problem please help me as i am new to this field

Comment: should i buy a flight controller ?if yes which is the cheapest one available on the market and theoreticalaly shoudln't the drone fly upwards without a controller if motors are running at same speed?shall i use cc3d controller

Comment: @RathoreBrothers Theoretically it would fly straight up, but this is not theory. Motors, props, and the air are all slightly inequal. You could buy a flight controller (thus making a conventional quad and getting rid of the arduino), but given that you've got a mpu 6050 it appears you're trying to use the arduino as a flight controller, so you will need to code a PID controller on the arduino to react to the difference between intended angular velocity (determined by your stick) and actual angular velocity (measured by the mpu)

Comment: @RathoreBrothers - in theory you can balance a pen on your fingertip, but in practice your reactions aren't fast enough. Drones are the same. You need electronic help.  The cheapest way to do this is the arduino and MPU6050 you're using, but unless you particularly want a software project, you should buy a flight controller. The CC3D is pretty old now, the current cheapest commonly used FCs use the F4 chip.